# Call a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am new to VBA and scripting in general. I was able to pull resources and create a user defined function in Excel that will return the distinct count of an array. The function is working properly when I call it within a cell in Excel.

Now, I would like to reference this function in a Macro to provide me with a message box stating the counts for two different columns. When I try to use the Macro I receive a 'Type Mismatch' error.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong - any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit: Included the COUNTDISTINCTcol code.

```
Sub GalileoCounts()

   Dim teachers As Long
   Dim students As Long

   teachers = COUNTDISTINCTcol("W2:W") 'ERROR HERE for "W2:W"
   students = COUNTDISTINCTcol("A2:A") 'ERROR with "A2:A" as well

   MsgBox "Teachers: " & teachers & vbNewLine & "Students: " & students, 
   vbOKOnly, "Galileo Counts"

End Sub
----
Public Function COUNTDISTINCTcol(ByRef rngToCheck As Range) As Variant

Dim colDistinct As Collection
Dim varValues As Variant, varValue As Variant
Dim lngCount As Long, lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

varValues = rngToCheck.Value

'if rngToCheck is more than 1 cell then
'varValues will be a 2 dimensional array
If IsArray(varValues) Then

    Set colDistinct = New Collection

    For lngRow = LBound(varValues, 1) To UBound(varValues, 1)
        For lngCol = LBound(varValues, 2) To UBound(varValues, 2)

            varValue = varValues(lngRow, lngCol)

            'ignore blank cells and throw error
            'if cell contains an error value
            If LenB(varValue) > 0 Then

                'if the item already exists then an error will
                'be thrown which we want to ignore
                On Error Resume Next
                colDistinct.Add vbNullString, CStr(varValue)
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            End If

        Next lngCol
    Next lngRow

    lngCount = colDistinct.Count
Else
    If LenB(varValues) > 0 Then
        lngCount = 1
    End If

End If

COUNTDISTINCTcol = lngCount

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    COUNTDISTINCTcol = CVErr(xlErrValue)

End Function
```

Comment: what are the parameters for the UDF countdistinct?

Comment: Can we see the code for COUNTDISTINCTcol()?

Comment: Without seeing the code we cannot help you. Also, if it works for `"A2:A"` or any other range, but not for `"W2:W"` we need to see both the function code and how your data looks like.

Comment: Without seeing the UDF, also try `COUNTDISTINCTcol "W2:W10"` ...see if that works.  AFAIK you'll *need* to put a last row in there, you can't just have a range `W2:W`.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne - I tried your suggesting and it did not work. I have tried changing it to "W:W" and that does not work either. I am trying to retrieve the count for the whole column.

Comment: You're missing a line continuation ` _` between `students,` and `vbOKOnly` in the `GalileoCounts` routine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `GalileoCounts` you are using `COUNTDISTINCTcol("W2:W")`.  That is passing a `String` to `COUNTDISTINCTcol` but `COUNTDISTINCTcol` is expecting a `Range` parameter. So, even if you put something like `COUNTDISTINCTcol("W:W")` it wouldn't work - it would need to be `COUNTDISTINCTcol(Range("W:W"))`.

Comment: An aside - sometimes my UDFs have to be called `myUDF Range("W:W")` instead of `myUDF(Range("W:W"))` ....is there a convention to when you use one format over the other? Is it done when creating the UDF, or how I call it?

Comment: Using `Range` is isolation is an implicit reference to the activesheet of the activeworkbook. It is better to explicitly refer to the workbook/sheet and then the range.

Comment: @BruceWayne - if you are returning a value use syntax of `lhs = func(parms)`.  Functions (including UDFs) should normally return values so that would be the normal syntax.  If you are not returning a value (i.e. calling a Sub, or calling a Function but wanting to ignore its return value) you would use a syntax of `func parms` or `Call func(parms)`.  If you try to use a `func parms` syntax but accidentally put brackets around the parms (i.e. `func (parms)`) then VBA will pass `parms` ByVal rather than ByRef - that will implicitly change `myUDF (Range("W:W"))` to be `myUDF Range("W:W").Value`

Comment: @ThunderFrame - Yes, I cringed when I typed `Range` without fully qualifying it.  But there's nothing in the OP's question that hints at an appropriate worksheet to refer to and, if the OP is calling `COUNTDISTINCTcol` successfully from the sheet that is active, there is a very high probability that the ActiveSheet is the sheet that the OP wants to use in this new code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :D